# Time Machine restore does not recognize sparsebundle password

Tags: time-machine, backup, password, restore, sparsebundle

I am trying to do a time machine system restore from an encrypted sparse bundle. I have a mac with OS X 10.10.2 and the sparse bundle is on a time capsule. I rebooted with cmd+R and selected “Restore from a Time Machine Backup”. I was asked for the time machine password and then selected the sparse bundle I wanted to restore. At that point I was asked for the sparse bundle password, which however the system keeps rejecting.

I am 100% sure the password is instead correct. To double check I restarted the mac and checked in the keychain, and the password is in fact correct. Also I could restore specific files from time machine without any problem. But when I try the system restore the way I just described, the system does not recognise that password as the correct one.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: Do you accidentally use a different keyboard layout in recovery mode?

Comment: no. same keyboard.

Comment: Your solution - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254163/macos-sierra-recovery-mode-does-not-have-terminal

Comment: Your solution - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254163/macos-sierra-recovery-mode-does-not-have-terminal

Answer (score 1):

Check if your password is longer than 15 characters, if it is just type the first 15.

Comment: it is 9 characters